# Discord bot not responding to messages but sees that I sent them

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have been working on a discord bot as a pet project and It connects and sees that the code is running and that I sent a message, but doesn't respond. My code is

```
import os


import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    print("Code is Working")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!'
    )
    print("What do do?")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("Works here, too")
    await message.channel.send('Bot is online and functioning properly.')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

It should see that I sent a message and respond. The print statements are working, the bot just isn't responding to the messages

Comment: enable message intents from developer portal.